# Why does Midousuji always say "Gross!"?

Tags: yowamushi-pedal

Midousuji always says "Gross!", but why does he do so?

For example, a scene where he says "Gross".

> You pedal so hard. Just how high is your cadence? *Gross*.
>
> [image]

Answer (score 2):

He seems disgusted by everybody that competes with fighting spirit, or with beliefs of friendship, for the team goals, self awareness, etc. It seems (as his point of view) that he rides a bike for the pure joy of win and all the other thoughts are superfluous to him.

In some of the later episodes, he shows empathy for the second climber of the Hakone Academy (Manami), because of this reason and Onoda in the image you showed is trying to reach his team to help them in the future obstacle (the next climbing zone), and he seems to enjoy himself, smiling at full throttle, because riding is fun, and that's gross!